# amend multiple data from an excel file into a new one

Tags: python, excel

The work is i am taking input from an excel file and it should result in two cases
Case 1: if record is found pass onto next record
Case 2: if record is not found print the registration number in an excel file stating result not found.
This is what i have so far

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("URL of input file")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("sheet name")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
a = worksheet.cell(1,0).value  
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.create_sheet("NIL Records", 1)
sheet["A1"].value = "Registration Number"
sheet["B1"].value = "Status"
sheet["A2"].value = a
sheet["B2"].value = "Registration Number Not Registered"
wb.save("path to the saved location file")
```

It is reading only the first record and i want to loop it until the list from the input file completes.
I want to loop the values of A2 and B2 and increment it
Any suggestions as to how can i work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code for iterative solution using xlrd to read and check the cell values iteratively and openpyxl to add Registration Numbers to an output workbook on the condition that their status is not found:

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl

# initialize workbook and sheet in xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("<InputWorkbook.xls>")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("<SheetName>")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

# create the workbook in openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

# go to first sheet and rename it
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "NIL Records"

# set column names on sheet
ws["A1"].value = "Registration Number"
ws["B1"].value = "Status"

# loop through the values in the worksheet
for row_idx in range(1, worksheet.nrows):  ## start at row 1 since column names in 0
    regNum = worksheet.cell(row_idx, 0).value
    status = worksheet.cell(row_idx, 1).value  #col_idx =1 since checking "Status" column
    
    # if Status is not found
    if status != 'Found':  # or whatever criteria indicates a found record
        regMsg = "Registration Number Not Registered"
        # go to max_row (i.e. highest row containing a value) and then down to first empty row and add values
        ws.cell(column=1, row=ws.max_row+1, value=regNum)  # openpyxl starts index at 1 so this is first col
        ws.cell(column=2, row=ws.max_row, value=regMsg)
        # print progress as sanity check
        print('added Registration Number {} to row {}' .format(regNum, ws.max_row))
        # save the openpyxl file
        wb.save('<OutputWorkbook.xlsx>')
```

Also note that each time you run the code, it will append all the same values to the openpyxl sheet. Make sure to clear the sheet or declare a new output sheet/file to avoid duplicates when re-running.